# Upgrading Laravel Apps

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

The next Laravel release is 5.5 which arrives this July. Now let's say I make a policy where I'll upgrade my web app every year in July/August to the latest version.

During that year of running the web app what should I do to keep it up to date with security fixes and bug fixes?

For example let's say I deploy on version 5.5.2 and by December there's a 5.5.8 what's the best way to keep the minor changes stay up to date without jeopardising the web apps availability?

I asusume you would need something to run commands like `composer update` Every so often etc. But what would the exact commands be and can they be run using Laravels scheduled so it is cross platform - if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will not run a composer update command as a cronjob. Packages can change and that can deprecate functions or change the way how they works: what will you do in this situation? Laravel itself has a great documentation (ex https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade) showing what will brake down of you upgrade from one version to another one.

The better approach is having a development branch where test the upgrade, fix pieces of code and then deploy everything online. Just in this way you will be comfortable not to have any surprise...

Comment: That's not for minor releases though is it?

Comment: Yeah, minor releases shouldn't broke your code. But pay attention that into your composer.json there will be a lot of different parts that could change too. Doing the autoupdate you have to study with attention how you write the definitions.